# python dataclass asdict ignores attributes without type annotation

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) explains how to use `dataclass` `asdict` but it does not tell that attributes without type annotations are ignored:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class C:
  a : int
  b : int = 3
  c : str = "yes"
  d = "nope"

c = C(5)
asdict(c)
# this returns
# {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 'yes'}
# note that d is ignored
```

How can I make `d` attribute appear in the returned dict without implementing the function myself?

Comment: It does partially explain it in [ClassVar section](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html#class-variables) but note that even if you omit annotations it still treats it as the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Any` as type annotation.
For example:

```
from typing import Any
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class C:
  a : int
  b : int = 3
  c : str = "yes"
  d : Any = "nope"

c = C(5)
asdict(c)
# this returns
# {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 'yes', 'd': 'nope'}
# Now, d is included as well!
```

Answer (score 0):

A cheesy and somewhat unprofessional way is to annotate it with any random string value.

So, for example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class C:
  a : int
  b : int = 3
  c : str = "yes"
  d: 'help,, i dunno how [a]ny of this w@rks!!' = "nope"

c = C(5)
print(asdict(c))

# this returns
# {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 'yes', 'd': 'nope'}
```

With some thought, this can actually be simplified down to:

```py
@dataclass
class C:
  a : int
  b : int = 3
  c : str = "yes"
  d: ... = "nope"
```